# Fish: Conditionally autoload subset of functions

Tags: function, fish

I'm testing out the `fish` shell, and I'm looking for a way to achieve what I was previously doing with my `.bash_profile`. I used a `switch` statement to discriminate by the hostname, allowing me to have 1 centralized/synced `.bash_profile`, which contains a separate set of aliases and functions for each machine it works on (e.g. work related stuff on my work computer, and person side-project related stuff on my personal computer).

I know autoloading functions in `~/.config/fish/functions` are `fish`'s equivalent of unconditionally defined functions in `bash`'s in `.bash_profile`. But is there a way to specify to autoload only a subset of those functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the knowledge of `$fish_function_path` from [Krutis Rader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4276647/kurtis-rader)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928083/3141234), I made the following folder structure in `~/.config/fish/functions`:

```
$ tree -FC ~/.config/fish/functions/
├── PersonalComputer1/
│   └── PersonalComputer1_only_function.fish
├── PersonalComputer2/
│   └── PersonalComputer2_only_function.fish
├── WorkComputer1/
│   └── WorkComputer1_only_function.fish
├── WorkComputer2/
│   └── WorkComputer2_only_function.fish
├── personal/
│   └── personal_only_function.fish
├── work/
│   └── work_only_function.fish
└── common_function.fish
```

And I set up my `$fish_function_path` by adding this to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
# Set up work/personal autoload function path
switch (hostname) WorkComputer1 WorkComputer2
    set -gx fish_function_path "/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions/work" $fish_function_path

case PersonalComputer1 PersonalComputer2
    set -gx fish_function_path "/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions/personal" $fish_function_path

end

# Set up host-specific autoload function path
set -gx fish_function_path "/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions/"(hostname) $fish_function_path
```

Resulting in a `$fish_function_path` that looks like:

```
/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions/WorkComputer1
/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions/work
/Users/USERNAME/.config/fish/functions
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.7.1/etc/fish/functions
/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.7.1/share/fish/functions
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I like the granular approach. I assume then that you put the same functions folder on each computer. In that case you could nest it like `common/work/WorkComputer1`. Then have a script called `__startup.fish` that added its current directory to `$fish_function_path` and runs `__startup.fish` in its parent directory. Then in your `config.fish` just source the lowest `__startup.fish` for ex. `source ~/fish/.config/fish/functions/common/work/WorkComputer2/__startup.fish` that matches your computer.

Comment: I didn't have my `WorkComputer1/` nested within `work/`. The two folders are on the same level (see the `tree` output above), and I sourced both "types" of scripts from my `config.fish`. But I like the idea, I'll tweak my structure to incorporate that!

Answer (score 4):

I do this exact same thing: my ~/.config/fish/config.fish contains

```
set host_config ~/.config/fish/config.(hostname).fish
test -r $host_config; and source $host_config
set -e host_config
```

and then the config.(hostname).fish contains  my functions and variable settings for that machine.

The one thing you have to be careful with is to remember that you *don't* want to funced/funcsave certain functions.

Answer (score 2):

Fish searches the directories in variable `fish_function_path` for autoloaded functions and loads the first one it finds. On my system this defaults to

```
$fish_function_path: set in global scope, unexported, with 4 elements
$fish_function_path[1]: length=36 value=|/Users/krader/.config/fish/functions|
$fish_function_path[2]: length=29 value=|/usr/local/etc/fish/functions|
$fish_function_path[3]: length=40 value=|/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d|
$fish_function_path[4]: length=31 value=|/usr/local/share/fish/functions|
```

So what I would do is prepend a directory whose name includes the host name and put all machine specific functions in that directory. And continue to put universal, non machine specific, functions in *~/.config/fish/functions*.